# dynamic background image style url

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-7.x

I would like to in fluid dynamically change background image url through content "image only" input. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26302379/is-it-possible-to-write-a-specific-query-in-typoscript)

But it is not exactly what I need. This is my code:

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-image: url('img/subpageHeader.jpg');">
    <div class="menu-trigger"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
    <p class="headerText"><f:format.raw>{header}</f:format.raw></p>
    <p class="logo pull-right">Sitename</p>
</div>
```

Can I make background-image url parameter dynamic without a complete new wrap?

Thanks

**RESOLVED**

*Get image URL from resourses:*

```
lib.headerimage = IMG_RESOURCE
lib.headerimage {
  file {
    import.data = levelmedia:-1, slide
    treatIdAsReference = 1
    import.listNum = 0
  }
}
```

*Include in style:*

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="background-image: url('<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.headerimage" />');">
```

I've put image in resources instead in content with image only.

Comment: Is this template of your plugin or what?

Comment: Template, jumbotron is from bootstrap, for which I need a background image.

Comment: I'm asking about the fluid template

Comment: ja, it is a part of a fluid template in header

Comment: ABoooo please concentrate ;) write what is this template from ? your plugin, page? give me it's path

Comment: tying to :), it is a template for a main page, sorry I'm a rookie in Typo3